# Is it possible to get last commit info for specific file in codecommit using python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, python-3.7, aws-codecommit, botocore

i am trying to create function that can give me specific file last changed date from AWS codecommit. can anyone suggest something so i can move ahead with this?